# Is there any way to get a quick render, like OpenGL for cycles and fisheye camera?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, camera

Is there any way to get a quick render, like OpenGL for cycles and fisheye camera? Maybe deleting all the materials alltogether, or giving them wireframes? (this could be the best option) ?

Comment: you can override the materials in the layers tab

Comment: Thanks! that helped a lot..but still the thing is that i need to save time by rendering, and a lot of time :/

Comment: do you want a script for wireframe ?

Comment: Hmmm, maybe if that helps to save time, yes, because i tried the modifier + material but it didn't help at all... :/

Comment: it is just for adding the modifier to all objects without going one by one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

override all the materials from the layer tab :

[image]

to add wireframe to all objects :

```
import bpy

for obj in bpy.data.objects:
    if obj.type == 'MESH':
        obj.modifiers.new("temp_mod", 'WIREFRAME')
```

run this and all the objects will be in wireframe render then use this script to remove it :

```
import bpy
for obj in bpy.data.objects:
    if obj.type == 'MESH':
        obj.modifiers.remove(obj.modifiers['temp_mod'])
```

Comment: It worked! but is that the same as the modifier? it still takes a lot of time to render

Comment: @beavoru do you need to apply all the modifiers at once ?